# need to get the top 10 rows in all the tables of all the databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
@command1 = 'select db_name
EXEC [?].dbo.sp_MSforeachtable 
@command2 = ''SELECT TOP 10 * from &''
@replacechar=''&''
'
```

The above query is giving me top 10 rows in all tables of all the databases, but I cannot get the table name and database name in the result. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Top 10 by what? Do you know what `ORDER BY` to apply to each table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
@command1 = '
IF not exists(select 1 where ''?'' in  (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb''))


EXEC [?].dbo.sp_MSforeachtable
 @command1 = ''SELECT TOP 10 db_name() AS DB_Name, ''''&'''' AS  Table_name , * from &'', @replacechar=''&'' '
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the db_name() and table name in your select statement:

```
  EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
   @command1 = 'select name from sys.databases where name <>''tempdb'' EXEC [?].dbo.sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = ''SELECT TOP 10 db_name() AS DB_Name, ''''&'''' AS Table_name , * from &'', @replacechar=''&'' '
```